# Hypervisor Issue WP8 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

after trying to start my first WP8 App I got an error saying that it could not create a virtual switch. So went to my BIOS and made sure all options are set according to the microsoft article about the prerequisites for running the WP8 Emulator.

But now the Emulator says, that Hypervisor cannot be found on the PC and Coreinfo also says, that hypervisor is not running:

[image: Coreinfo]

I hope you got a solution for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a troubleshooting page for the emulator: hopefully it helps!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68

Answer (score 3):

First question, is this PC running or bare metal or as a virtual machine? Because you cannot use WP8 emulator when running in a virtual machine.
Second, make sure Hyper-V is enabled - you need Windows 8 Pro x64 for this. If it's not enabled, go to "Turn Windows features on or off" and here enable the Hyper-V and restart your PC. All should work now.

Comment: Hey,
1 - Yes I have installed Windows 8 on my PC, its no VM. I also got Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and ofc the WP8 SDK.
2 - The Feature is turned on. I also tried to turn it off and on again, after setting the right BIOS Settings.

Comment: Correction - you can run the emulator in VMs that allow hardware virtualization. Tested on VMware.

Comment: Do you have latest BIOS version and have you checked the BIOS, if you haven't disabled any virtualization CPU features like DEP or VT-x?

Comment: When I enable the "Safe Execution" Hypervisor is present, but then SLAT and VMX are not enabled...

Comment: When the Hyper-V is running - VMX and EPT will show the "-",
but that is OK.